# Sybase instance fails to start: Error: 905, Severity: 17, State: 1

Tags: sybase, dbtable

My Sybase instance fails to start.

Database log show:

> 00:0002:00000:00001:2015/05/12 15:51:44.51 server  The transaction log
>   in the database 'sybsystemdb' will use I/O size of 4 Kb.
>   00:0002:00000:00001:2015/05/12 15:51:44.52 server  Resident Node id:
>   926a95836174 00:0002:00000:00001:2015/05/12 15:51:44.55 server 
>   Transaction coordinator initialized. 00:0002:00000:00001:2015/05/12
>   15:51:44.55 server  Database 'sybsystemdb' is now online.
>   00:0002:00000:00001:2015/05/12 15:51:44.57 server  Increase the config
>   parameter 'number of open databases' to avoid descriptor reuse. Reuse
>   may result in performance degradation. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12
>   15:51:44.59 server  Error: 905, Severity: 17, State: 1
>   00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.59 server  Unable to allocate
>   a DBTABLE descriptor to open database 'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop
>   another database before opening this one, or ask your System
>   Administrator to raise the configuration parameter 'number of open
>   databases'. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.59 server  Error:
>   905, Severity: 17, State: 1 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.59
>   server  Unable to allocate a DBTABLE descriptor to open database
>   'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop another database before opening this one,
>   or ask your System Administrator to raise the configuration parameter
>   'number of open databases'. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.59
>   server  Error: 905, Severity: 17, State: 1
>   00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.59 server  Unable to allocate
>   a DBTABLE descriptor to open database 'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop
>   another database before opening this one, or ask your System
>   Administrator to raise the configuration parameter 'number of open
>   databases'. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60 server  Error:
>   905, Severity: 17, State: 1 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60
>   server  Unable to allocate a DBTABLE descriptor to open database
>   'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop another database before opening this one,
>   or ask your System Administrator to raise the configuration parameter
>   'number of open databases'. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60
>   server  Error: 905, Severity: 17, State: 1
>   00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60 server  Unable to allocate
>   a DBTABLE descriptor to open database 'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop
>   another database before opening this one, or ask your System
>   Administrator to raise the configuration parameter 'number of open
>   databases'. 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60 server  Error:
>   905, Severity: 17, State: 1 00:0002:00000:00005:2015/05/12 15:51:44.60
>   server  Unable to allocate a DBTABLE descriptor to open database
>   'sybsystemdb'. Close or drop another database before opening this one,
>   or ask your System Administrator to raise the configuration parameter
>   'number of open databases'.

When trying to increase number of database files:

```
C:\>isql -Usa -P<password>
1> select count(*) from sysdatabases
2> go

1> sp_configure "number of open databases", 20
2> go
Msg 225, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'ILVQA3SYBAS157', Procedure 'sp_configure', Line 232:
Cannot run query--referenced object (name NAME NOT RECOVERABLE) dropped during
query optimization.
```

Sybase version:

```
C:\>isql -Usa -P<password>
1> select @@version
2> go
```

> Adaptive Server Enterprise/15.7/EBF 21339 SMP SP101 /P/X64/Windows
>   Server/ase15
>            7sp101/3439/64-bit/OPT/Thu Jun 06 12:11:05 2013

Please advice,
Shay

Comment: Looks like you found your answer.  You were not able to do this while the server was running because the `sybsystemdb` database was not able to open, and it's required to make any configuration changes.

Answer (score 1):

The default number of databases per Sybase instance is 12.
Once you reached it, and created a new database (no. 13 and above), you will probably not get any error and database will be created.
The error will arrive once you bounce the instance.

To solve this, you need to edit the parameter file: **`C:\{Sybase Location}\{SERVERNAME}.cfg`** and change the value for:
**number of open databases** under **[Meta-Data Caches]** section.

Comment: I edited your answer a bit to make it more widely applicable, since the location of the Sybase installation, and the name of the config file can vary.  Also, don't forget to accept your answer, since you did find the solution.